# api json use 4 views and push id from json list to next view

Tags: ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4

I have done alot of google searching and I can refrase my question.
I wounder how I push params from the lan_view to the kommuner_controller

so in the lan_view it will list all the states and the state name is a link_to. so when I click on it it will take that states id and push it to the next view so that view will show the citys for that state. I need it to push the id from the @results.each do to the kommuner view so that the url in the controller kommuner will be

```
http://api.arbetsformedlingen.se/af/v0/platsannonser/soklista/kommuner?lanid=20
```

I have 4 controllers

```
def lan
    base_url = "http://api.arbetsformedlingen.se/af/v0"
    lan = "/platsannonser/soklista/lan"
    @results = JSON.parse(open(base_url + lan, "Accept" =>application/json",
    "Accept-Language" => "sv").read)

end

def kommuner
    kommuner = "/platsannonser/soklista/kommuner?lanid="
    @results = JSON.parse(open(base_url + lan, "Accept" =>application/json",     
    "Accept-Language" => "sv").read)
end
```

and here is my lan_view

```
<tbody>
<% @results["soklista"]["sokdata"].each do |sokdata| %>
  <tr>

    <% links = sokdata["namn"].downcase.gsub(' ','_').gsub('ä','a').gsub('å','a').gsub('ö','o').downcase.to_s %>
    <%= lan_id = sokdata["id"] %>
    <td><%= link_to sokdata["namn"], links %></td>



    <td><%= sokdata["antal_platsannonser"] %></td>

  </tr>
<% end %>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I am using a api that can show xml and json and I am going with json here.

this list all the states in sweden
http://api.arbetsformedlingen.se/af/v0/platsannonser/soklista/lan

and you can see that there is a ID node

```
<sokdata>
<id>20</id>
```

so if you put the state id in this url
http://api.arbetsformedlingen.se/af/v0/platsannonser/soklista/kommuner?lanid=20

it will list all the citys in that state
and here is also a ID node

```
<id>2081</id>
<namn>Borlänge</namn>
```

Comment: Your question is confusing. You say you're using JSON but your examples are XML. What have you tried to generate the link? Imagine that a colleague asked you this question, what would you need to answer it? Add that information to your question.

Comment: yes, I dont know why chrome spit it out in xml since the default is in json, no ide here.

Well, I need to know how to get the id from the output that the url i giving me and push that in to the url with params. Something like this <%= link_to 'city', cityp_path %>

and in my routes file I think i need to add the params id or am I totalt wrong here ?

I can make a view for all of the city and states, but I dont think that is good practice. So I wounder how do I make a link that push the id from that view to the next